# How to predicate for first occurrence on a fetchRequest

Tags: iphone, ios, nsfetchedresultscontroller, predicate

I'm trying to find a way of predicating for the first occurrence of an event on a given day. So say an event occurs multiple times during the day (range 1-16), I only want it to return the first occurrence and then look for the next first occurrence on the following day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do this with one fetchRequest; you'll need to do two.

For each day, just use a predicate to limit to occurrences after the beginning of that day, sort in ascending order of date, and fetch only one item:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"YourObject" inManagedObjectContext:context];
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date > %@", beginningOfDay];
request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES]];
request.fetchLimit = 1;
```

Of course, you'll want to check the item you get to make sure it's still on the same day. Then, repeat for the next day.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I've tried this already. Sorry should have posted the code. The problem with this is setting the fetch limit to 1 is too severe. All subsequent events are lost.

Comment: My bad, I missed that part of your question. I updated my answer. But the short version is that you won't be able to do it with just one `NSFetchRequest`.

Comment: I had a feeling that I would need more than one fetchRequest. I was hoping that there would be a smart way to do it with SUBQUERY. It's unfortunate that NSPredicate doesn't support conditionals (switch, if, etc.)